# Install NLTK in python 2.7 for 64-bit machine

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, nltk

How to install NLTK in Python2.7? There is NLTK package for 32 bit but what about 64? Moreover, I am unable to install NLTK wheel file by pip.

Comment: http://www.nltk.org/install.html - what machine are you on? If the instructions here dont work how dont they work? What happens? what errors do you have?

Comment: if you are using windows, I think there is no 64bit version

Comment: okay i got it installed in 32 bit. Now its giving error after "import nltk"

Comment: Keep a look out on https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1079

Comment: I have downloaded set-up from this <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk'> but when I try to run this it says no Python found in this registry. I tried pasting the set-up in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages also yet it is not been installed. Also I am using Windows-7. If anyone can guide will be of great help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. `conda create -n nltk_env python=2.7`
2. `source activate nltk_env`
3. `conda install nltk -c intel`
4. try importing it like below

   ```py
   import nltk
   ```