# nltk for python 3.6 in windows64

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm new to `python`, I'm using Windows 10 and have  python36  and I basically have to use `nltk` for my project and i basically have two questions.

- 1 I heard `pip` is automatically downloaded for versions 3+ but when I type `pip install nltk` in command prompt im getting the following error even though i added its path `"C:\Users\dheeraj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip36"` in advanced settings and ya in above path i tried pip36 and pip in both cases result is same.

  > 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"
- 2 In www.nltk.org I found `nltk` for mac, unix and windows32 but not for windows64 ,does that mean it doesnt support for 64bit or is there any way for me to install `nltk`.

Comment: c.f https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1079

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612023/install-nltk-in-python-2-7-for-64-bit-machine

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Comment: @dheeraj C:\Users\dheeraj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
Should be the path provided. You should not include the pip itself

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as you, but I accidentally found `pip.exe` in my `python` directory, so I navigated to said directory with CMD and ran the command `pip install -U nltk` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Run the Python interpreter and type the commands:

`import nltk`>>> 
`nltk.download()`>>> 
A new window should open, showing the NLTK Downloader. Click on the File menu and select Change Download Directory. For central installation, set this to `C:\nltk_data (Windows)`, `/usr/local/share/nltk_data`(Mac), or `/usr/share/nltk_data (Unix)`. Next, select the packages or collections you want to download.

If you did not install the data to one of the above central locations, you will need to set the NLTK_DATA environment variable to specify the location of the data. (On a Windows machine, right click on “My Computer” then select Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > User Variables > New...)

Test that the data has been installed as follows. (This assumes you downloaded the Brown Corpus):

`from nltk.corpus import brown`>>> 
`brown.words()`>>> 
`['The', 'Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury', 'said', ...]`
Installing via a proxy web server

If your web connection uses a proxy server, you should specify the proxy address as follows. In the case of an authenticating proxy, specify a username and password. If the proxy is set to None then this function will attempt to detect the system proxy.

`nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128', ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))`>>> 
`>>> nltk.download()`
Command line installation

The downloader will search for an existing nltk_data directory to install NLTK data. If one does not exist it will attempt to create one in a central location (when using an administrator account) or otherwise in the user’s filespace. If necessary, run the download command from an administrator account, or using sudo. The recommended system location is `C:\nltk_data (Windows); /usr/local/share/nltk_data (Mac); and`/usr/share/nltk_data `(Unix). You can use the -d flag to specify a different location (but if you do this, be sure to set the NLTK_DATA environment variable accordingly).

Run the command python -m nltk.downloader all. To ensure central installation, run the command sudo python `-m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data all.`

Windows: Use the “Run...” option on the Start menu. Windows Vista users need to first turn on this option, using Start -> Properties -> Customize to check the box to activate the “Run...” option.

Answer (score 3):

Directly Search for `pip` folder and navigate throught that path example:
C:\Users\PAVAN\Environments\my_env\Lib\site-packages\pip> 
Run `cmd`
and then run the command 
    `pip install -U nltk`

Answer (score 3):

Following are the steps I followed to resolve this issue:

1. Click on Python 3.6 Module Docs (32 bit). This will open in your default browser.
2. Click on pip(Package), displayed at the end of the page.
3. You will be redirected to a page displaying details of the package. Find the exact path from there. It will be something like `c:\users\grove\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip`
4. Run this on cmd prompt. 
   [image]
5. Once you're in pip folder type `pip install -U nltk`
6. Go back to Python Shell and type `import nltk`

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to use the Anaconda on Windows. Anaconda has nltk version for Python 64-bit. Now I'm using Python 3.6.4 64-bit and nltk.

Under python shell run:

`import nltk 
 nltk.download()`

then the downloader will be open in new window and you can download what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First install the module
like `pip install -U nltk`
and the use the import statment in the command prompt or IDLE

```
import nltk
```