# Error while installing NLTK with Python3.6

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, python-3.6

I tried to run "pip install nltk" but getting so many error. Though I tried to install dependencies which are causing error, but they are not getting installed as well.

```
Invalid requirement: 'nltk()'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packagi
ng\requirements.py", line 92, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsi
ng.py", line 1617, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsi
ng.py", line 1607, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsi
ng.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsi
ng.py", line 3376, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsi
ng.py", line 1383, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsi
ng.py", line 3164, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 4), (line:1, c
ol:5)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install
.py", line 82, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packagi
ng\requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, pars
e error at "'()'"
```

Please check screenshot for error: [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2BIJ.jpg)

Comment: Py3.6 is not yet officially support, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1659

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313776/nltk-for-python-3-6-in-windows64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you dont have permission to install packages. Try running the command line as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Python package managment best practice is to **create a virtual environment**, see http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

First install the `virtualenv` library for the local user

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

See [How to install python modules without root access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access) and [PEP370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)

For Python2.7, create a virtual environment under the directory `my_nltk_project`

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 my_nltk_project
```

Or in Python3:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 my_nltk_project
source my_nltk_project/bin/activate
```

**Make sure Python3 is Py3.4 or Py3.5, Py3.6 is not yet officially support, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1659**

Now you should be within the virtual environment and your command prompt will look like this:

```
(my_nltk_project):~$
```

Now do a pip install:

```
pip install nltk
```

Optionally, use the `-U` option is to upgrade `nltk` (`pip install -U nltk`)

After you're done with the environment, simply do this to leave the environment:

```
(my_nltk_project):~$ deactivate
```

To reuse the environment:

```
:~$ source my_nltk_project/bin/activate
```

---

Alternatively, you could try this without the virtual environment:

```
pip install --user nltk
```

---

If you're on a Windows machine, it's strongly recommended that you use `conda` to manage NLTK packages, see https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9