# Remove common words from a list of strings. Python NLTK

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am trying to remove a list of the common words from a set of strings (text) from a python pandas dataframe. The dataframe looks like this

```
 ['Item', 'Label', 'Comment']
```

I have removed stop words already, but I did a word cloud and there are still some more common words that I want to remove to get better insight into this problem.

This is my current working code that does good but not good enough

```
# This recieves a sentence 1 at a time
# Use a loop if you want to process a dataset or a lambda
def nlp_preprocess(text, stopwords, lemmatizer, wordnet_map):
    # Remove punctuation
    text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', text)
    # Remove tags
    text=re.sub("&lt;/?.*?&gt;"," &lt;&gt; ",text)
    # Remove special characters and digits
    text=re.sub("(\\d|\\W)+"," ",text)
    # Remove stop words like and is a and the
    text = " ".join([word for word in text.split() if word not in stopwords])
    # Find base word for all words in the sentence
    pos_tagged_text = nltk.pos_tag(text.split())
    text = " ".join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, wordnet_map.get(pos[0], wordnet.NOUN)) for word, pos in pos_tagged_text])
    return text

def full_nlp_text_process(df, pandas_parms, stopwords, lemmatizer, wordnet_map):
    data = preprocess_dataframe(df, pandas_params)
    nlp_data = data.copy()
    nlp_data["ProComment"] = nlp_data['Comment'].apply(lambda x: nlp_preprocess(x, stopword, lemmatizer, wordnet_map))
    return data, nlp_data
```

I know i want to something similar to this, but I do not know how I should put it in there to remove the words and where I should put it in (i.e. in the text processing or the dataframe process)\

```
fdist2 = nltk.FreqDist(text)
most_list = fdist2.most_common(10)
# Somewhere else
for t in text:
   if t in most_list: text.remove(t)
```

Comment: please refer this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926366/calculate-tfidf-matrix-without-stop-words-in-python)

Comment: if you know how to remove `stopwords` then create list with words which you want to remove and use it like you used `stopwords`

Comment: in Python better create new list with words which you want to keep instead of removing words from list which you use in `for`-loop. The same way you removed `stopwords` - you created new list with words which you wanted to keep.

Comment: My question would be where I should put it. Because my cleaning code works line by line which may not get all the common words for the whole document. But then again I am not 100% sure if that is correct or not as it is an assumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a new way of doing it and it worked well.
The first method would be this

```
def find_common_words(df):
    full_text = ""
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        #print(row['Comment'])
        full_text = full_text + " " + row["ProComment"]
    allWords = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(full_text)
    allWordDist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in allWords)
    mostCommon= allWordDist.most_common(10)
    common_words = []
    for item in mostCommon:
        common_words.append(item[0])
    return common_words
```

And then you will need this method to finish things up.

```
def remove_common_words(df, common_words):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        sentence = row["ProComment"]
        word_tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)
        filtered_sentence = " "
        for w in word_tokens:
            if w not in common_words:
                filtered_sentence = filtered_sentence + " " + w
        row["ProComment"] = filtered_sentence
```

This way you take in a dataframe and do all the processing through that.